# Web service giving "could not load file or assembly error"

Tags: iis

I just moved a website and related web service from IIS6 to 8.
The website works fine, but the webservice is giving the following error:

> Server Error in '/CreditCardService' Application.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The web service config file do not have any related lines in it.
Only the website web.config has any related lines in it, see below.

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: You can try adding <remove assembly="System.Web.Mvc"/> in your web service's web.config file.